# Insert Into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, mysqli

I am working with php and mysql for the first time.  The goal is to have a table that store email addresses to form a mailing list for a newsletter. my table Emails has 2 columns ID (INT auto increment) and email (varchar, 255)

I can connect to the database but I cannot write to it.  I think my problem is in the syntax of my INSERT INTO statement.  I have seen many examples and they seem to use different syntax specifically around the values. 
form code:

```
    <form method="post" action="email.php" class="form-container">
    <div class="form-title"><h2>Sign up for my newsletter!</h2></div>
    <div class="form-title">Email Address</div>
    <input class="form-field" required="required" placeholder="example@mail.com" type="text" name="newEmail" /><br />
    <div class="submit-container">
    <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
  </form>
```

php code:

```
    <?php
    $dbHost = "localhost";
    $dbUser = "input";
    $dbPass = "input";
    $dbName = "MailingList";


$conn= mysqli_connect ($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die("FAIL:". mysqli_connect_error() . "(" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")");
}

$addEmail = "mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['newEmail'])";

$query ="INSERT INTO Emails (email) VALUES ('$addEmail')"

mysqli_close($conn)
?>
```

Comment: Given the answers below, you're also missing a closing semi-colon `$query ="INSERT INTO Emails (email) VALUES ('$addEmail')"` you can use two of those answers to piece everything together.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Working on it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the query, not just write it.

```
$query ="INSERT INTO Emails (email) VALUES ('$addEmail')";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

If you use a prepared statement, you can save yourself the trouble of escaping:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO Emails (email) VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_POST['newEmail']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

---

If you want non-procedural style (aka oop), this would look like the following

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Emails (email) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['newEmail']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I edited my code and now it is creating records, but still is not actually writing the email to the record.  Any idea why?

Comment: So you have empty rows? As I said, you need to execute the query - then be sure to check for errors as well.

Comment: just to be clear in php this line is how you execute the query correct? mysqli_query($conn, $query);  i will have to work on this more later, but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed to add the `$conn` i.e database link to the `mysqli_real_escape_string` and also, you have wrapped the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` inside the `"`, so it consider as `string`. So remove the `"` and use it. Try this,

```
$addEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['newEmail']);
                                 ......^
$query ="INSERT INTO Emails (email) VALUES ('$addEmail')";
```

instead of

```
$addEmail = "mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['newEmail'])";
```

Comment: You're welcome Krish. I deleted my comment after noticing it.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the quotes around your escape function. This turns it into a string instead of actually escaping the value:

```
$addEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['newEmail']);
```

Comment: `$addEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['newEmail']);` ;-) since it's `mysqli_*`

Answer (score 1):

```
$addEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['newEmail']);
```

https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string

string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )